# Prime Ideals of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What are the prime ideals of the ring $\mathbb{C}^{n}$? I was thinking that it is $e_{i} : i \in [n]$, where $I = e_{i} = \mathbb{C}^{(i)}= (\mathbb{C} , \dots , 0 , \dots , \mathbb{C})$, where the $i^{th}$ copy of $\mathbb{C}$ is not in $e_{i}$  because taking quotients yields $\mathbb{C}$ which is a domain? Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You found $n$ prime ideals, but did not explain why these were all the prime ideals. So your reasoning is not complete.  But your candidate set of primes is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_i=(0,...,1,0...)$ $1$ at $i$-place $e_i.e_j=0, i\neq j$.  There exists $i_0$ such that $e_{i_0}$ is not an element of $I$, otherwise since $I$ is a vector space, $I=\mathbb{C}^n$.

Let $i$ different of $i_0$, $e_ie_{i_0}=0$ implies that $e_i\in I$ since $I$ is prime.